# configure two routers to one T1

Tags: networking, t1

We have a router hooked up to our T1, and the router went down the other day and caused our phones to go down so i had an idea to use a backup router. I know very little about networking. Is it possible to hook up 2 routers to a T1 so that if one fails, the other will kick on and take over until the other kicks back on? I understand that with this, everything being routed to one router will have to turn around to go back through the other router and will cause a stop of like 50 seconds or so. but thats no big deal. just want to know if this is possible. thanks in advance.

Comment: Punch [T1 failover switch](http://www.valiantcom.com/aps/t1-4-protection-switch.html) into your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 1):

Typically in an active/failover environment, there will be 2 internet connections.

With 2 internet connections, BGP would be an option, and is how I would do it (depending on your setup, gear, etc.)  I've not seen what you're looking for done with a T1.